# how to create login and signup on same page using CakeDC plugin in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I want to Create login and sign up on same page using CakeDC plugin but the Form->create variable is giving me errror

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create($register); ?>
```

because it not defined, i tried to give url for the register funtion but its not working...

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create($register,['url' => ['action' => 'register']]); ?>
```

Any Guidence...??

Also guide me the right way to use login, signup using CakeDC plugin in different pages in pop -up....

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference between a popup and a regular form. Use a form like this one

```
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('username', ['required' => true]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password', ['required' => true]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__d('CakeDC/Users', 'Login'), ['onclick' => '...']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And create an onclick javascript ajax post to your login action.

Comment: And what about the register page because it uses <?php echo $this->Form->create($register); ?> this code for validation and submitting data into database

Comment: in that case, you need to provide a $register variable User entity from the controller

Comment: Thank you, I will look  forward for it and Check this out https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues/511